# Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function. Prove that $g_{1} = g_{2}.$

Tags: functions, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following:

$Problem:$ Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a function. Assume that there are $g_{1} : Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ g_{1} = i_{Y}$ and $g_{1}\circ f = i_{X}$ and $g_{2} : Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ g_{2} = i_{Y}$ and $g_{2} \circ f = i_{X}$. Show that $g_{1} = g_{2}$.

I am still trying getting the hang of proving functions, but this is what I have as my attempt so far:

$\textbf{Proof}.$
Let f be surjective and $f \circ g_{1} = f \circ g_{2}.$ That is, $g_{1}(f(x)) = g_{2}(f(x))$ for all $x \in X$. For every $y \in Y$, there exists $x \in X$ with $f(x) = y$. Therefore, $g_{1}(y) = g_{2}(y)$ for all $y \in Y$, or $g_{1} = g_{2}$.

Will this suffice as a accepted proof or should I approach it in a different way? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't just assume $f$ is surjective, you need to show this.  Aside from that the proof is fine.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, totally screwed the assumption. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot start the proof stating “let $f$ be surjective”. What if it is not?

Actually, $f$ *must* be surjective, because if $y\in Y$, then $y=f\bigl(g_1(y)\bigr)$. And $f$ must be injective too, because $f(x)=f(x')\implies g_1\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=g_1\bigl(f(x')\bigr)\iff x=x'$. So, $f$ is a bijection. Therefore, it has one and only one inverse. But you know that both $g_1$ and $g_2$ are inverses of $f$. Therefore, $g_1=g_2$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it could also be proven directly using compositions.  You know that $f \circ g_1 = i_Y$ and $g_2 \circ f = i_X$, so think about what happens if you compose $g_2$ on the left of the equation $f \circ g_1 = i_Y$.